# JDBC connection string for LDAP authentication postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection-string

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database via JDBC authenticating through LDAP.

What does the connection string look like in this case; I tried something like below but it errors out.

```
jdbc:postgresql:@ldap://example.com:389/db01,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: What would be the meaning of thet URL? If you are looking for something like libpq's [LDAP lookup of connection parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ldap.html), there is no support for that in the JDBC driver, You'll have to write the JNDI lookup yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP authentication parameters need to be specified in `pg_hba.conf`.  From the Java app's perspective, you should use a typical connection string as though you were using any other authentication method (i.e., password or md5).

More information available in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-ldap.html)